# How can I send and get with this.$router.push the params between two components

Tags: vue.js

I have two components.

The first one:

This component has this one:

```
this.$router.push({path: '/dte', params: { id: 1 }});
```

I am sending and redirecting to /dte

And I have a second one which it has in the created part of the vuejs code this:

```
export default {
    created() {
       alert(this.$router.params.id);
    }
}
```

I wonder:

- How can I check if id is defined?
- I wonder why does it display this error - Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"?

Thanks

Comment: It should be `this.$route.params.id` (not `$router` with a 2nd "r")

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, there are two [globals objects](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) injected by vue-router:

- $router: The vue-router instance
- $route: The current route state described in an object

Here, you have to check for `this.$route.params.id` to get the current route parameter.

Comment: but I wonder how can I get the params sent in the push? I mean the id? how can I get that param?

Comment: You can access it using.   this.$route.params.id